# Dell Lattitude 5511 with Ubuntu 23.10 suspend not working

Tags: drivers, kernel, suspend, dell, 23.04

Unfortunately, I upgraded my Ubuntu version from 22.04 to 23.10 and got an issue with a laptop suspension.

After clicking on the "Suspend" button screen goes black, the laptop fan stops for a second, and then starts working again. The screen is still blank. As I understood, the laptop wakes up immediately.

I tried:

1. Use nvidia-driver-535 and xorg nouveau driver;
2. Switch to another kernel version (6.5.0-15-generic, 6.2.0-39-generic, 5.19.0-50-generic);

To check what is going on when suspended I use:

```
journalctl --grep='suspend|sleep' --no-pager --since="-1day"
```

The output:

```
21:32:46 dell-5511 systemd[1]: Reached target suspend.target - Suspend.
21:32:46 dell-5511 systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend.target - Suspend.  
21:32:46 dell-5511 systemd-logind[1059]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
```

What should I try to make suspend work correctly?

Comment: @guiverc thank you for your reply!
I upgraded the OS to 23.10. The situation with suspension is the same, unfortunately